# Generate unit and instrumentation code coverage reports on android studio 2.0

Tags: android, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco, android-studio-2.0

I found some articles for android studio 1.x and they don't seem to work for 2.x, has anyone achieved this using jacoco and imported the report to sonar ?